# W10 Cursor gets stuck when going from top monitor to bottom but fine from side to side

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, mouse, navigation

So recently upgraded from w7 and now i have a very annoying issue: when i try to go from my bottom screen to the top one, the cursor gets stuck unless i go really fast. The same happens going down, but it works perfectly fine when going to the side one, heck it's actually easier to go around than straight up. Any ideas to get rid of this "feature"?

[image: my display layout]

Comment: This article suggests that a slight adjustment to how close together the monitors are in the alignment configuration can eliminate the resistance. https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/94778-tweaking-resistance-passing-cursor-between-multiple-monitors.html

Comment: thanks, i thought it was find since it would snap into place, but turns out i had to drop the top monitor on top of the bottom one by like 5-10% for it to work properly. Issue is not fixed, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior (called Sticky Edges) can happen if the virtual monitors are not quite touching.

According to this article -- https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/94778-tweaking-resistance-passing-cursor-between-multiple-monitors.html -- you can make the stickiness go away if you move the monitors slightly closer together -- maybe even overlap them -- in the multiple-monitor layout interface.

Comment: that was it, had to overlap or else it wouldn't work.